# LISP file loads but get ; error: no function definition: DCL-FORM-SHOW

Tags: autolisp

I have a lisp routine (quite lengthy) that was written for AutoCAD 2012, works in 2012.
We have upgraded to 2014 and need to get this lisp file up and running smoothly, parts work but I get the error above.  I think I have a problem with open dcl and its current version for ACAD 2014.
2014 is version 19.1 is there a dcl version 19.1.  My lisp routine loads in 2014 but the associated dialog box does not show up.  My users tell me it was working and has mysteriously stopped working a couple days ago.

I have 0 knowledge of the autolisp language.

Any help offered is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread on Autodesk's Community Forums: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Visual-LISP-AutoLISP-and-General/issues-with-a-lisp-routine-when-upgraded-to-Acad-2014-fro-Acad/td-p/4901892

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the current OpenDCL Runtime. Get it [here](http://opendcl.com/go?runtime&dev)